# Print an image in Javascript without opening a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, iframe

I want to print an image rendered by html2canvas (front) without opening a new window. So I used a hidden iframe that will display a window containing the image I want to print. This window prints the image in an onload event.

Javascript Code

```
html2canvas($('#front'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        front = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $("<iframe>")          // create a new iframe element
            .hide()            // make it invisible
            .attr("src", "../html/myid_print_page.html") // point the iframe to the page I want to print
            .appendTo("body");                                       
    }
});
```

HTML Code (myid_print_page.html)

```
<html>
    <head>          
    </head>
    <body onload="print()">
        <img id="front" src=""></img>       
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is:

1. No image has been printed.
2. How will I pass rendered image(front) to "myid_print_page.html"?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: What is the problem then??

Comment: @EvanKnowles --> I already edited my post.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt -->  I already edited my post

Comment: why not use a @media CSS query for print that isolates the elements you want to print? Then you don't need to go through html2canvas which may fail with CORS situations, and the standard print invoking can be used (**[some info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)**)

Comment: [CSS @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)